# recognizing of logged in client - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made function for registration of clients, firstly they have to register then they are written in txt file. Now, they have to log in, and when they are logged in, is it possible for my program to know which client is logged in? I need to know his username,name and lastname which is in my file by index[0],[2],[3], they are written in like this (john10|john123456|John|Frusciante|buyer). Here is my log in function:

```
client_list = []

def clients():
    with open("svi.txt","r") as f:
        all_h = ["username","password","name","lastname","role"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[all_h[count]] = i
                count += 1
            client_list.append(dicct)
clients()

def log(username,password):
    for r in client_list:
        while r["username"] == username and r["password"] == password:
            if r["role"] == "buyer":
                return buyer_menu()
            elif r["role"] == "manager":
                return manager_menu()
            elif r["role"] == "seller":
                return seller_menu() 
    return False

def login():
    x = False

    while x == False:
        username = input("Input username: ")
        password = input("Input password: ") 
        x = log(username,password)
        if x == False:
            print()
            print("Wrong username or password, try again: ")
            print()
    print()
login()
```

So, do I have to modify something here or?
Btw, my register function required 4 inputs (username,password,name and lastname), the role part I added automatically.

Comment: What do you mean with logged in? Are you executing this program multiply times?

Comment: I need later in other functions to know which client is logged in so he can buy some tickets without entering his username name and lastname, and I need to save all of that that in other txt file

Comment: You can return `r` from `log` on a successful login, and after that get a menu.

Comment: I dont understand, sry